# Show $n^{\frac{1}{n}}>(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$ for $n\geq3$

Tags: inequality

Show $n^{\frac{1}{n}}>(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$ for $n\geq3$.

I took the derivative of $x^{1/x}$ and it is a decreasing function for $x>e$.

I was just trying to think of another way I can prove this without taking the derivative. I was thinking of using induction but I wasn't able to make progress. I tried to use logs to prove an equivalent statement but I wasn't able to move forward.

Comment: Try induction, as we are in the realm of natural numbers, not real numbers.  Base case: prove $3^{1/3} > 4^{1/4}$.

Comment: @amWhy Quoting from OP's question: " *I was thinking of using induction but I wasn't able to make progress*. I tried to use logs to prove an equivalent statement but I wasn't able to move forward". Your statement is equivalent to putting $n=3$. How does this help? We can use induction.  But, your comment already *repeats* where the OP got stuck, I think.

Comment: @amWhy I really can not understand your second comment.  Or something else.

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to $n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}\geq n+1$, which is equivalent to $n^{\frac 1n}\geq 1+\frac 1n$, which is equivalent to $n\geq (1+\frac 1n)^n$. Use the fact (c.f. the definition/basics of $e$ in many analysis books) that $(1+\frac 1n)^n<e<3$, we see the inequality is true with $n\geq 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n\geq 3$. Then by the binomial formula
$$
(1+\tfrac{1}{n})^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n^k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\left(1\cdot\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\dots\frac{n-k-1}{n}\right) < \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} < e < n,
$$
and so $(n+1)^n < n^{n+1}$, which is equivalent to your inequality.